# How to disable backticks operator in php?

Tags: php

I disabled functions in php.ini, but backticks operator still work!

```
disable_functions = “apache_child_terminate, apache_setenv, define_syslog_variables, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, eval, exec, fp, fput, ftp_connect, ftp_exec, ftp_get, ftp_login, ftp_nb_fput, ftp_put, ftp_raw, ftp_rawlist, highlight_file, ini_alter, ini_get_all, ini_restore, inject_code, mysql_pconnect, openlog, passthru, php_uname, phpAds_remoteInfo, phpAds_XmlRpc, phpAds_xmlrpcDecode, phpAds_xmlrpcEncode, popen, posix_getpwuid, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, posix_setuid, posix_uname, proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_nice, proc_open, proc_terminate, shell_exec, syslog, system, xmlrpc_entity_decode, curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source, symlink”
```

[image: shel result]

How disable this operator?

System linux from richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest docker container

PHP 7.2.4 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2018 02:39:05) ( NTS )

Comment: PHP 7.2.4 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2018 02:39:05) ( NTS )

Comment: System linux from richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest docker container

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be accepted as such: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70231201/2115770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this only manifests itself when calling with `php -r`. When used in PHP file, the backtick operator doesn't work, as expected. I guess, the actual shell is calling the `echo 1` and it's injected into the PHP code, before its execution by PHP, so you're actually executing:

```
echo 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the php.net:

> The backtick operator is disabled when safe mode is enabled or shell_exec() is disabled.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: Yes, but safe mode is removed http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php. `shell_exec` i disabled (see screenshot).

Answer (score 2):

Try call it like

```
php -r "echo \`echo 1\`;"
```

So it will return

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function shell_exec() in Command line code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in Command line code on line 1
```

---

### Incorrect

If you run

```
php -r "echo `echo 1`;"
```

Bash will run it before PHP, and convert to

```
php -r "echo 1;"
```

Then will send it to the php
Then php will return `1` to you